# Php - inserting data into data suddenly not working anymore

Tags: php, mysqli, wamp

After writing this code I proceeded with other pages, when I returned later on to continue work the code didn't work anymore. After reverting all changes the code still didn't work. The problem is with inserting the data into the database but only with the campaign and region's, the system and planets work just fine. The value of camp_id for the planets etc is 0.

The code is:

```
// Put the campaign in database.
$sql = "INSERT INTO campaigns (moderator) VALUES('$log_id')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$camp_id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);

// Put system in database
$sql = "INSERT INTO systems (campaign, allegiance) VALUES('$camp_id', '$system_allegiance')";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$system_id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);

// Put planets in database
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare("INSERT INTO planets (system_id, campaign_id, size, moon, planet_nr) VALUES ('$system_id ', '$camp_id', ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $planet_size, $i_planet, $i);
foreach ($planet_list as $row){
    $i = $row[0];
    $planet_size = $row[1];
    $i_planet = $row[2];
    $stmt->execute();
}

// Put region's in database
$stmt = $db_conx->prepare("INSERT INTO regions (system_id, campaign_id, planet_id, region_id, region_type) VALUES ('$system_id ', '$camp_id', ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $planet_id, $region_id, $region_type);
foreach ($region_list as $row){
    $planet_id = $row[0];
    $region_id = $row[1];
    $region_type = $row[2];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

As far as U see there is no issue with the code itself. So I'm wondering where the problem might be. I'm using wamp to run everything.

Comment: @JohnReyM.Baylen This is __mysqli__ not PDO

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I've set the default value of everything in my database as 0, even though all of them get overwritten when the entry is made it does solve the problem.